# How to create a AggregationOutput object, to use it later on

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I feel like I have had to unlearn something about programming lately. I keep going in circles.

I have a try catch in the method I want to use an AggregationOutput object. After the catch, I want to return what I hope are the values of the field I am looking for. That values are what I obtain from an aggregate method, which I can't find any way of storing other than AggregationOutput object.

Something like this:

```
List<DBObject> results = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
 AggregationOutput output = new AggregationOutput(results);
 try
    {
```

or

```
   AggregationOutput output = new AggregationOutput(null);
    try
    {
```

I am not able to create an AggregationOutput WITHOUT immediatly storing in it the values of the aggregate method. Like this:

```
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(pipe);
```

This seems counter intuitive at the very least, if not plaing wrong, which makes me suspect I'm missing a BIG concept which isn't allowing me to use this method (aggregate) properly.

I would like to know what that object need to be declared on it's own, so I can declare, go into the try, instance the object, and then after the catch, return said object.

If there is any other way of doing this, without using AggregationOutput, I would also like to know, because I do not find any way.

edit:

```
@GET
    @Path("/get/{item}/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String get( @PathParam("item") String item, @PathParam("id") String id)  {

        AggregationOutput output;
        try
        {

            List<DBObject> result = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
            output = new AggregationOutput(result);
//here I would operate with the output, then return the result as I usually do, an array or some other object that can be transformed into json
```

Comment: you cannot do a declare AggregationOutput output; and then an instantiate output = new new AggregationOutput(results); later on?

Comment: No, I can't, if I do the instantiation in the try it says: "The constructor AggregationOutput(List<DBObject>) is not visible". And that works for any combination I come up with. And I'm even trying to emulate how it's done in the library itself so I'm kind of lost

Comment: have you just skipped the try and marked the method with a throws?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I believe you are saying like maybe I forgot the try block and just wrote down the throw part? If that's the case, no, I do wrote down the instantiation you suggested in the try part, after declaring it outside the try.

Comment: is it in the main method?

Comment: I added a bit more code in the main post, this is currently how I have it and one of the ways it gives me the "constructor is not visible" error" @Newton , thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is worth a try.

instead of doing

```
public String get()
{
    try {}
    catch() {}
}
```

try doing

```
public String get() throws ExceptionName {}

//assuming you will use get in main
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    try { get(); }
    catch (ExceptionName e) {}
}
```

otherwise link me the code and i will try debugging it at my end.

Comment: That could work, unfortunately I don't have a main (and I'm not really sure but I don't think I need one either, in my case). I went with another solution that has to prove to be good enough but so far it works. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: I would like to know the other solution

Comment: So the original goal was to somehow create a distinct query for mongo to get 1 field to be retrieved and 2 queries as conditions. This is fairly easy with find, but with distinct I wasn't having success with it. I looked arround but there were no examples so I wasn't sure if I was doing it wrong, or it wasn't something supposed to be done with that syntax. With this search I found a way of doing the same, but using a somewhat complex search with AggregationOutput. I finally found doing that it is indeed possible to add two parameters to a BasicDBObject and use them as query for distinct.